# fill entire widget opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

So I'm working with a 2d array, and I'm trying to display it on a widget using opengl. It seems to work fine, but it does not fill the widget properly. Rather than filling it evenly it's moved to the top right as seen in the image below. How can I get this to be centered? 
[image]

```
int x = -0.1;
int y = -0.1;
float lengthX = 0.9 / ROW;
float lengthY = 0.9 / COLM;

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLM; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        } else {
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Q3 Q4 Q1 Q2
            glVertex2f((-x) + 2 * i * lengthX, (-y) + 2 * j * lengthY);
            glVertex2f(x + (2 * i + 1) * lengthX, (-y) + (2 * j + 1) * lengthX);
            glVertex2f(x + (2 * i + 1) * lengthX, y + (2 * j + 1) * lengthY);
            glVertex2f((-x) + 2 * i * lengthX, y + 2 * j * lengthY);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your matrix set to? Also, what are the variables `ROW` and `COLM` set to?

Comment: @Alex Larsen they are both set to 100, `const int ROW = 100, COLM = 100;`

Comment: @Alex Larsen that is an array that holds values of either 0 or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your code is wrong with it's variables; Such as `int x = -0.1`.

Now, to fix the problem just add this to the beginning of your code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

The problem was that you're using the default matrix setup. Basically, it ranges from `-1, -1` to `1, 1`, instead of `0, 0`, to `1, 1`. I can't quite read your code, but if you can edit the `glOrtho` function's first 4 parameters (the last two shouldn't effect anything) to change the visible range of what you're drawing.

Just to explain a bit more, the first parameter sets the left side, the second right, the third bottom, and the fourth top. So `glOrtho(0, 600, 800, 0)` means setting a vertex to `0, 0` means it's showing on the top left, while a vertex set to `800, 600` will be showing on the bottom right.

Your setup was only showing a part of what it was supposed to show because the center of it, was the corner of your screen.

Comment: is there a way to keep aspect ratio if i change the size of array? when i change it goes beyond the widget and i can't see some of it like here http://i.imgur.com/B1sPmjt.png

Comment: I don't know what you're saying. If you mean adjusting the size of what you see, you can use `glViewport(0, 0, width, height)`. If you mean making sure it doesn't stretch, that requires either adjusting the viewport (as I just mentioned) accordingly with a bit of math and drawing like you have it, or using vertex shaders, which are a lot more work and require more math, but can do better things.

Comment: Can I ask you some questions about what I am working on here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42765/openglhelps